# Async vs Threads for mass, low latency http requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, asynchronous, synchronous

I need to do **mass HTTP**(for a financial app, host doesnt offer better API) **Requests**(around **800 per second**) and **process** their **response**(in JSON, usually not more than 1kb large) **with low latency**(doing only deserialization and comparing some values) to finally *make another request based on the response(**time between Response and next request shouldnt be more than 1-2 ms**).*

Currently, I use traditional Threads with synchronous Requests where around 50% of the threads only do requests after 40-60 seconds and the other 50% are always requesting
While this approach worked fine with around 50-100 requests per seconds, I experienced that with 800 requests per second the time between a response and the next request of a thread is way too high(often 50-200ms).

As I want to fix that I'd like to ask:
**1. Are Asynchronous Operations the better approach for that?**
*Read a lot about Scalability and Responsiveness gaining with Asyncs, but not sure if its good for low latency(Context switching, Task creation etc. overhead )*
**2. Can I tweak the Thread aprroach? (Independent from Quest #1)** *I was thinking of something like giving threads a higher priority(over `.ThreadPriority`) when they currently process the responses, but that didnt really work out/Maybe completely stop execution of the other threads while processing*
**(3. Which Class/Lib for HTTP Request should I use?)** *Currently using `HttpWebRequest`s, which are a bit faster than the `HttpClient` ones in my tests, or should I use something else?*

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Before anything, does the server support that response time at high throughput (800req/sec)?

Comment: Yes ofc + the time between requests(way too high atm) is independent from the server

Comment: You might consider scaling this horizontally as well - perhaps a queuing system such as MSMQ would be of benefit to you, with clients pulling from the queue across other physical machines.

Comment: Highly recommend using TPL Dataflow for this type of work.

Comment: Hmm. You might need to shed some layers of abstraction in order to get the performance you want (e.g. raw sockets in the worst case). Also, if you're doing any POST/PUT requests, be sure to set `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` to false.

Comment: The delay you're noticing now could also be due to the fact that you're either hitting the thread pool capacity (if you're using it) or the CPU capacity if you're using non-pooled threads. The thread pool starts throttling when it's at capacity.

Comment: That's quite a ferocious rate. First you need to be sure that every bit of network between you and the source can handle it. In my experience, SOHO routers run out of resources before you can hit such rates.

Comment: @Cameron Set it to false, also disabled NagleAlgo and set DefaultConnectionLimit to something high

Comment: @MarcelN. Im using raw threads + CPU @ Task Manager doesnt exceed 40%

Comment: I'd consider connecting a socket directly to source and chatting http. HttpWebRequest becomes quirky at high request rates and isn't too friendly with memory.

Comment: And definitely go async. Do consider TPL Dataflow, as advised above. It's a really cool way to deal with high throughput apps of this nature.

Comment: Try Parallel.ForEach + async

Comment: At the moment we should find out where the delay is coming from. Async does nothing at all to speed up the work being performed. All it does is free up threads and enable you to have less of them. None of the concurrency limits inherent in the system go away.; How many threads do you have? You have removed the connection limit for HttpWebRequest, right?

Comment: @usr Connection Limit removed and around 1300 Threads
I guess its coming from scheduling all these threads running with same prio, so I think Asyncs could help by freeing up threads

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls OK, 1300 threads are many... A case for async. No need to go 100%, though. You can achieve quick wins by asyncing the longest-blocking calls or waits.

Answer (score 3):

I went through and solved this exact problem (for downloading lots of XML files from a server in parallel) and in my experience, using Async was about 20%-50% faster, depending on the size of the file.

Unfortunately this was a few months ago, but I was using a WebClient within each request and just doing a WebClient.DownloadString, so if this is your use case it might work for you.

The real answer is: **try both and profile it**.  It shouldn't be hard to switch between the two!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` performs well enough for your needs. One challenge with that is setting the number of parallel connections. You can't use the `HttpWebRequest.ConnectionLimit` property directly, so you have to go through the `ServicePointManager`:

```
ServicePoint servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
servicePoint.ConnectionLimit = connectionLimit;
```

You can then use tasks for your parallel operations, and wait on the result with `Task.WhenAll`.